# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type string and char

Tags: c#, string, char, type-conversion

I'm using `char`, but I'm getting confused because I know I have to convert this `char` into `string` data type.

```
else if (mode.Equals("Update"))
        {
            char id = char.Parse(txtuserId.Text.ToString()); //conversion as i told before

            string newName = txtname.Text;
            string newemail = txtemail.Text;
            string newpassword = txtpassword.Text;
            string newaddress = rtbaddress.Text;
            string newphoneNumber = txtphoneNumber.Text;
            string newroleName = cmbrole.Text;

            users updatedusers = (
                from x in db.users
                where x.id==id // THE WRONG ONE
                select x
                ).First();
        }
```

[image: The image maybe helpful..]

Comment: Try adding .tostring in x.id

Comment: string id =txtuserId.Text;

Comment: what is the type of column `id` in the table `users`

Comment: @EarvinNillCastillo : where x.id.ToString = id? still error..

Comment: @ManishSingh if i use string id =txtuserId.Text, the data on the table must be string. but the requirement is char..

Comment: @un-lucky : the data type is char(5)

Comment: have you tried `where x.id== txtuserId.Text`

Comment: @un-lucky: sorry still error :')
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2a3yLvf0rMKOTNWS0pCbXpVOUE

Comment: what is it, the error saying now?

Comment: @un-lucky: from your answer, this is the error message
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2a3yLvf0rMKZXY5Y3ZfZWpxc2M

Comment: use `==` for comparison, you are using `=`, `where x.id== txtuserId.Text`

Comment: @un-lucky https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2a3yLvf0rMKZWlZc2JnOVBBS3c
ya ya that's works! thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering the question based on the comment

> @un-lucky : the data type is char(5);

Which means that column is capable of storing a character array of length 5, Now consider that input, that is `txtuserId.Text`. which itself is a string, as we already knows string is a character array, so that you need not to convert that by using `char.Parse` you can directly compare them. So the where clause would be `where x.id==txtuserId.Text` in that case.

**Additional notes:**
You need not to use a `char.Parse`to get a character from a string, instead of that you can use the index to take a character at particular place from a string. Consider that you wanted to get the first character from a string, in that case you can use like the following:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtuserId.Text))
  char firstChar = txtuserId.Text[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible to **parse a character from a string** but not parse a **string having multiple chars as chars**. It should be a case to case basis situation.

If the **txtuserId** which I guess is a textbox has it's length **limited to one character only** it may be possible to use

```
char id = char.Parse(txtuserId.Text.ToString());`
```

If the txtuserID is not limited to one character only you can use this code:
(Getting an character you want by it's index)

```
char[] id = txtuserId.Text.ToCharArray();
char mID = id[n]
```

But seriously in your case, I guess, that is not what you need. You've been redundant in your code. If string is what is required in the SQL like code in the bottom part of your code then don't convert it to char array then convert it to string. I suggest you to this:

```
else if (mode.Equals("Update"))
        {
            String id= txtuserId.Text; // change this part

            string newName = txtname.Text;
            string newemail = txtemail.Text;
            string newpassword = txtpassword.Text;
            string newaddress = rtbaddress.Text;
            string newphoneNumber = txtphoneNumber.Text;
            string newroleName = cmbrole.Text;

            users updatedusers = (
                from x in db.users
                where x.id==id // leave it as it is
                select x
                ).First();
        }
```

In this code you're not be able to get confused because string is not reconverted but rather placed properly where it should be.

Comment: thanks for the advice